# How to add dir props in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am from web development background. I created one application with arabic and english language.

I set rtl and ltr in initial load like : 
Arabic

```
 I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
```

English

```
 I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
```

This is working perfectly but i want set rtl or ltr manually in some component like in html.

I tried use [link](https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-direction) but not working.

can anyone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find solution but no such solution available.

Standard and usual way to dynamic direction of component is reload application.